# Reasons not to develop Apps with a jailbreak iPhone as the only testing device

Tags: testing, ios, jailbreak

I'm looking for reasons developers ought to consider before developing and testing applications and games on a jailbreak device. My conviction is that if you want to publish your App to the App Store, you better make sure you always test on a non-jailbreak device. Eg. if you are a serious developer, what do you have to consider before jailbreaking your only development device respectively buying a second untampered device just for development.

The legal implications are fairly well known but it doesn't hurt to reiterate them. What I'm more interested in are all the technical reasons why development on a jailbroken iPhone will make your life harder (or sometimes easier if that exists, too).

For example, I've read that jailbreak devices can cause adverse behavior, bugs and crashes which will not appear on a non-jailbreak device. But what those issues are remains in the dark. I'm looking for concrete evidence of bugs and misbehavior that is relatively common (eg occured to you, or someone who blogged about it) when you do test on a jailbreak device.

Comment: Of course you should always test on a non-jailbroken device; the first rule of testing is to test as many different cases as possible, especially those your user is most likely to be running. But where did you hear that a jailbroken device experiences "adverse behavior, bugs, and crashes"? That sounds more like hype than fact.

Comment: I read this in two comments here on Stackoverflow, and I have always had the suspicion that there will be very specific problems associated with jailbreak devices. I want to learn about them because I don't have a jailbreak device but I'm giving support to those who might.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always want to test on the device and configuration you will be releasing for. If your going to release for jailbroke devices, test on jailbroke. If you intend to release through the app store, test on an unbroken devices.

I haven't work on a jailbroke device but I think the biggest issue would be that jailbroke devices do not enforce the same security restrictions as non-jailbroke devices. It would be easy to have a segment of code that relies on access that disappears on a non-jailbroke device.

You always want to develop and/or test on device as close to your projected average user as possible. One big mistake that developers have made for decades is building and test new software on their high-horse power developer stations. They see that the softwares runs fine on there above average systesm but when they release the software to average users running on average systems, the software is to slow in real-world use. That wouldn't be such an issue on mobile devices but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

there is one big problem that I've took more than a week to figure out:

**inAppPurchase development doesn't work on JB devices** (it gives InvalidProductIDs for all inApps)

(some reports say it's for JB with AppSync installed)

Comment: This is purely false. Jailbroken device have absolutely no issue with InAppPurchase development. I've done it. AppSync had to have been the reason you saw issues with InAppPurchases.